# how to make passwordless connections from IP1 to IP2?

Tags: ssh-keys

1. I had create authentication
   " $ssh-keygen -t rsa "
2. create .ssh directory on 10.10.10.5
   " $ssh root@10.10.10.5 mkdir -p.ssh "
3. upload generated public keys to - 10.10.10.5
   " $cat.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@10.10.10.5'cat>>.ssh/autorized_keys' "
   But i got this issue
   -bash: cat.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
   ssh: connect to host 10.10.10.5 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailabl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting to follow this [article](https://geekflare.com/linux-ssh-key-exchange/).

Works for me.

Maybe you suffer from missing file permission/access.